# ¿Sacar informacion de una tabla ?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Necesito sacar la informacion de una tabla con selenium, python.

Cuepo html:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Valor de la Prima</td>
                            <td style="text-align: right;">$ 1.176.256</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>IVA</td>
                            <td style="text-align: right;">$ 223.489</td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><strong>Total Prima</strong></td>
                            <td style="text-align: right;"><strong>$ 1.399.745</strong></td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

hay dos tablas con la misma clase, la primera y esta a la cual le quiero extraer informacion.

tenia un codigo pero con beautiful y me recomendaron mejor hacerlo con selenium directamente.

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con el siguiente código puedes imprimir la información de la tabla:

```
# obtenemos los elementos que satisfacen la clase enviada como argumento
table = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('table table-bordered')
# obtener todas las filas de la tabla
rows = table[1].find_elements_by_tag_name('tr') # indexamos en 1 ya que dices que necesitas la segunda tabla
# iteramos en cada una de las filas almacendas en rows
for row in rows:
    col = row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')[1] # se puede indexar con 0, 1, 2... depende del tamanio de la tabla y la columna que queramos
    print(col.text) # imprimimos el texto de los elementos
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha funcionado perfectamente, lo unico que quite:
table = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('table-bordered')
Le quite el primer table.